# My query won't work due to order by Clause

Tags: mysql

I am writing query for displaying data and added order by clause in that query.
My query Is

```
SELECT * FROM `coupons` 
WHERE `status` = 'A' &&  `type` = '2'    
&&  `time` > CURDATE() && `start_date` <= CURDATE()
order by `stocks` asc
```

In above query it get sorted by 'stocks' but in some cases stocks is zero, that case I want show this row at the last.

Comment: Simplest way off the top of my head, entirely in MySQL:  create a stored function that returns the value you pass it if nonzero, or the highest possible value if zero.  (Or, something like `order by (case when stocks = 0 then 2000000000 else stocks end)` in the query.  But eh.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
order by CASE WHEN `stocks` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END asc , `stocks` asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, (if(`stocks` != 0,`stocks`,"")) as newstocks FROM `coupons` 
WHERE `status` = 'A' &&  `type` = '2'    
&&  `time` > CURDATE() && `start_date` <= CURDATE()
order by newstocks asc
```

Use above code.

Answer (score 0):

By default it is asc so you don't have to mention it.  Try the below one

SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE status = 'A' && type = '2' && time > CURDATE() && start_date <= CURDATE() order by case stocks != 0 then stocks end, stocks

It will first list the items with stocks is nozero and then list the rows with stocks=zero